# How to create tgz file with version using npm pack?

Tags: npm

I'm trying to create npm package (tgz) without publishing however it's not clear how to specify the version of the module.

When running **npm pack** it creates filename with version 0.0.0, does anyone has example to share?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`npm pack` reads the version from your `package.json` file.  You can set the version with the `npm version` command:

`npm version 1.2.3`

If you don't yet have a `package.json` file, create it with `npm init`.

Answer (score 9):

above answer is valid, 
just adding some code and a *small tip*:

```
 { 
    "name": "my-cool-package",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    (...rest of you package.json details)
}
```

***npm pack*** command in any terminal will give you *my-cool-package-1.0.0.tgz.*
This will have all contents from you package.

Extra info:

In case you want to ignore any file eg node_modules add those into .npmignore in the same folder and they will be ignored.